# Mac OS X Terminal title incorrectly displaying "Python"

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I have my Mac OS X terminal set to display only the active process name. But for some reason when I am at the shell prompt the title displays "Python". But when I type anything at the prompt, it displays "bash" like it should. Any ideas on why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Ok, here is *exactly* what happens.

1. I open Terminal, either from a dead quit, a new window/tab, or even after another command finishes.
2. The Terminal title for the tab and window displays either `Python` or `python`.
3. The Terminal title goes back to `bash` like it should once I type even a single character at the prompt.

Comment: When does it happen? When you open Terminal, for new windows, new tabs? What do your bash_profile etc. look like? My windows first displays "login", then "bash" after opening; do yours? Does it happen when you display more information in the window title? Do new windows open with the default login shell or another command?

Comment: It displays when I open a new tab or window or open Terminal after quitting. When I open a new tab or window it flashes through two other titles before displaying Python. But when opening from a dead quit it shows login, then bash, then Python. And this is my .bash_profile: http://pastie.org/1196666

Comment: Oh, and here is my .bashrc if that would help as well: http://pastie.org/1196668

Comment: What is in your `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` or similar that's related to `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: Here is what I have setting my `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `PS1`: http://pastie.org/1196784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's `autojump`. Try removing the lines related to `autojump` from your `bashrc` and look what happens.

(I think possible offenders are [line 87](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_builtin.htm) (`complete`) and [line 105](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) (`PROMPT_COMMAND`), but I'm not sure)

Comment: I removed autojump and it works! Thank you so much!