# Is there a directory history for bash?

Tags: bash, history, file-search, cd

Is there something like bash's reverse-search-history (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>), but for only directories?

I have some deep folder hierarchies that I want to jump to, so I'd like to use something like reverse-search-history, but it only looks for folder names and gives me absolute paths.

Essentially, it would give similar results to using `!?` but only matching commands with `cd` in the front, you can step through results, and full paths.

So far, the best solution I've found is [bashmarks](https://github.com/huyng/bashmarks).

Comment: I recently [started using z](https://github.com/rupa/z) and that seems to work so far, but I used it for a few paths.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump):

> One of the most used shell commands is “cd”. A quick survey among my friends revealed that between 10 and 20% of all commands they type are actually cd commands! Unfortunately, jumping from one part of your system to another with cd requires you to enter almost the full path, which isn’t very practical and requires a lot of keystrokes.
>
> autojump is a faster way to navigate your filesystem. It works by maintaining a database of the directories you use the most from the command line. The jumpstat command shows you the current contents of the database. You need to work a little bit before the database becomes usable. Once your database is reasonably complete, you can “jump” to a commonly "cd"ed directory by typing:
> `j dirspec`

Comment: It might lead to issues with [Terminal's title](http://superuser.com/questions/195380/mac-os-x-terminal-title-incorrectly-displaying-python).

Answer (score 11):

There is

```
cd -
```

that is "cd[space][hyphen]" command, which goes to the directory you were before, essentially a "history of depth 1". Repeated "cd -" switches back and forth between two directories.

Quoting man page:

> The following operands shall be supported: [...]
>
> When a [hyphen] is used as the operand, this shall be equivalent to the command:
>
> ```
>       cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd
> ```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a real built-in directory history.

Comment: There is `pushd dir` `popd` pair which can store your history stack of directories. This is really helpful in scripts that operate in different folders.

Comment: I know of `pushd` and `popd`, and it is also mentioned here already.

Answer (score 7):

You can build your own `cd` command with `pushd`, `popd`, `dirs`
builtin commands.

### Usage

- `cd --`   ( list current history )
- `cd -num` ( go to num directory )
- `cd -`    ( go to previous directory )

---

```
function cd () 
{ 
    local hnum=16;
    local new_dir index dir cnt;
    if ! [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        if [[ $# -eq 2 && $1 = "--" ]]; then
            shift;
        else
            if ! { 
                [ $# -eq 1 ] && [[ $1 =~ ^(-[0-9]{,2}|-|--|[^-].*)$ ]]
            }; then
                builtin cd "$@";
                return;
            fi;
        fi;
    fi;
    [ "$1" = "--" ] && { 
        dirs -v;
        return
    };
    new_dir=${1:-$HOME};
    if [[ "$new_dir" =~ ^-[0-9]{,2}$ ]]; then
        index=${new_dir:1};
        if [ -z "$index" ]; then
            new_dir=$OLDPWD;
        else
            new_dir=$(dirs -l +$index) || return;
        fi;
    fi;
    pushd -- "$new_dir" > /dev/null || return;
    popd -n +$hnum &> /dev/null || true;
    new_dir=$PWD cnt=1;
    while dir=$(dirs -l +$cnt 2> /dev/null); do
        if [ "$dir" = "$new_dir" ]; then
            popd -n +$cnt > /dev/null;
            continue;
        fi;
        let cnt++;
    done
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Where do you put it? ~/.bashrc? EDIT: OK, I tried and it works, quite nice

Answer (score 5):

bash has pushd/popd/dirs. 
I have this in my .bashrc to auto-push directories onto bash's stack.

```
#let cd also pushd directories into stack. Use popd to reverse stack
function cd ()
{
  if [ -e $1 ]; then 
    pushd $1 &> /dev/null   #dont display current stack 
  fi
}
```

Pop these using `popd` and display the stack using `dirs`

Answer (score 4):

I have made a [script](https://github.com/imambungo/dirjump) that has similar functionality to [oh-my-zsh's `dirs -v`](https://superuser.com/a/664139/943615) command that works on bash. If you have ever use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), you might have noticed that the directory history provided by the command `dirs -v` will be reset every time you exit the terminal. It won't happen if you use this [script](https://github.com/imambungo/dirjump), however.

The functionality:

- Show the list of 10 most recent used directories with `d`.
- Jump to any directory in the list by typing the number of the directory in the list.
- A directory path will be put at the top of the list every time you visit a directory.

Comment: Am using zsh & didn't realise there was `dirs -v` so would need a bash built-in. Btw I installed zsh without any framework and it looks like it is still available to me. Anyways: thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have had good experience with [z-jump](https://github.com/rupa/z) It allows completion, although only for the final destination, not stepping through a path. It does show the full path upon tab completion however.

Answer (score 2):

A pure Bash implementation for a persistent directory history menu:

```
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

cdHistoryFile=~/.bash_cdhistory

cd() {
    builtin cd $@ && echo $PWD >> $cdHistoryFile
}

cdh() {
    local IFS=$'\n'
    local directories=()
    for line in `tac $cdHistoryFile`; do directories+=($line); done
    cnt=${#directories[@]}
    for ((i = 0; i < cnt - 1; i++)) {
        for ((j = i + 1; j < cnt; j++)) {
            [ "${directories[$i]}" == "${directories[$j]}" ] && unset directories[$j]
        }
    }
    directories=("${directories[@]:1:${1:-15}}")
    local select=0 subset=("${directories[@]}")
    until [ $select -eq 1 ]; do
        select dir in ${subset[@]}; do
            case $REPLY in
                q) select=1; break ;;
               \.) subset=("${directories[@]}"); break ;;
               .*) subset=($(printf '%s\n' "${subset[@]}" | egrep "${REPLY:1}")); break ;;
                *) cd $dir; select=1; break
            esac
        done
    done
}
```

Explanation:

`cd()` wraps the `cd` shell builtin with a function that writes directory changes to a file. `cdh()` displays a selection menu of the last n-number of unique directories (in descending order from most recently accessed).

Usage:

```
cdhistory: cdh [n]

    Options:
      n         Get the latest number of unique directories [default: 15]

    Selections:
      q         Quit
      .         Display the original list
      .<regex>  Filter the current list
      #         Change directory
```

Example:

```
[jdoe@localhost /] $ . ~/.bash_profile && cdh
 1) /home/jdoe/tmp/2/3/1
 2) /home/jdoe/tmp/3
 3) /home/jdoe/code/projects
 4) /home/jdoe/tmp/2
 5) /home/jdoe/code/projects/cloud/pipeline
 6) /home/jdoe/tmp/1
 7) /
 8) /etc
 9) /usr/etc
10) /usr/share/libtool
11) /home/jdoe/tmp
#? .tmp
1) /home/jdoe/tmp/2/3/1  3) /home/jdoe/tmp/2      5) /home/jdoe/tmp
2) /home/jdoe/tmp/3      4) /home/jdoe/tmp/1
#? .3
1) /home/jdoe/tmp/2/3/1
2) /home/jdoe/tmp/3
#? 2
[jdoe@localhost /home/jdoe/tmp/3] $
```

Comment: One thing missing is find-as-you type like Ctrl-r. Looks easy to integrate with fzf like [bulletmark's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1646028/11808). Also, bash_cdhistory seems to have unbounded growth, but could be easily truncated in cdh. I wonder if you could use `uniq` somehow to avoid the double for loop? [Maybe awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444406/how-to-delete-duplicate-lines-in-a-file-without-sorting-it-in-unix).

Answer (score 1):

Just to chime in with my own experience, I wrote a simple script to address this requirement some time ago, it overrides the builtin cd command with a simple function which appends the new directory location to a history file, a python script is then used to provide a bash interface which dynamically updates an ordered list of directories as you enter search terms, somewhat like the reverse command search of bash.

It's available on [git-hub](https://github.com/gearoid-murphy/bash-directory-history) for those that are curious.

Comment: rock on gearoid

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend my `ltcd` for quick navigation through directory history:

https://github.com/dczhu/ltcd

[image: cd demo gif]

It provides the following features to make life easier:

- Global dir listing, which shows recently visited dirs from all terminal tabs/windows.
- Local dir listing, which is local to current shell session.
- Both listings support quick navigation by using j/k (go down/up), numbers, and word searching.
- Global free jumping (e.g. "cd dir" or "cd ar" to go to /path/to/foo/bar/directory/).

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest another solution: **fuzzy path search**

- [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

  After having it run in the background, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open a window where you can type a fuzzy string to find directories. After you select one and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, fzf will change to that directory.

  [image: fzf]
- [fuzzy bash completion](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion)
- [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/command-t):

  [image: Command-T in action]

See also

- [Find file modes in console (fuzzy completion)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5154539/995714)
- [Command-T for shell](https://superuser.com/q/392496/241386)

There are also various shells and shell extensions that support [partial path autocomplete](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/94) and [fish](http://fishshell.com/) is one of them

For example `cd /v/l/fsck` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will convert the path to `/var/log/fsck/`. `cd /u/s/appl` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand the path to `/usr/share/applications/`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own [`cdhist` tool](https://github.com/bulletmark/cdhist) for this about 15 years ago and have used it all day every day since. It replaces your `cd` command with an alias which keeps track of the directories you visit so that you can `cd --` to list them and then select one. It also [integrates with `fzf`](https://github.com/bulletmark/cdhist#fzf-integration) if you prefer to fuzzy search over previously visited directories.

Comment: This looks very close to what I was looking for! One thing that's not clear from the readme is whether `cd /usr/local/share ; cd ../bin` will add `/usr/local/bin` or `../bin` to the history. I assume the former?

Comment: Well you did two `cd` commands so it adds `/usr/local/share` to the history then adds `/usr/local/bin` to the history. I don't understand why you would think it would work any other way? BTW, it takes seconds to `pip install` this (or unstall it) so just try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add this code snippet to your `~/.bashrc`, which

1. provides a custom cd command

   ```
       function cd ()
       {
           exists=false
           for dir in "${CDHIST[@]}"; do
               [ "$dir" == "$1" ] && {
                   exists == true
                   break
               }
           done

           $exists || {
               len=${#CDHIST[@]}
               ${CDHIST[$len]} = "$1"
           }

           builtin cd "$1"
       }
   ```
2. and provides a cd history search command.

   ```
   function cdhist ()
   {
       #TODO: Make this magical.

       for dir in "${CDHIST[@]}"; do
           echo "$dir"
       done
   }
   ```

Of course, the cdhist command I provided is very basic, and not what you wanted; but it is conceivable to use case statements or parameter expansion to achieve something similar to what you want.

You could even add some "Programmable completion" function, which could be used to add the full `cd /path/to/mydir` command based on a unique sub-string of `/path/to/unique/mydir`, although that method would still require you to type `cd unique/mydir<tab>`.

Comment: I misread your code and found bash's `dirs` command which does essentially the same thing as `my_dirs`, but on one line.

Comment: Cool. So not only does bash support it; it _implements_ it. I wish I had more time to study bash's deep magic. Of course, this only supports remembering pushd, not cd. But I suppose `alias cd=pushd` would be the most elegant form.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WCD](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/#WCD_ANCHOR) which is a `cd` replacement that stores the list of directories you've changed into. That's exactly a directory history list that you can view with any text editors

Running `wcd foo` will show a list of the directories containing foo and you can choose one of them to jump into

> `Wcd` is a command-line program to change directory fast. It saves time typing at the keyboard. One needs to type only a part of a directory name and `wcd` will jump to it. `Wcd` has a fast selection method in case of multiple matches and allows aliasing and banning of directories. `Wcd` also includes a full screen interactive directory tree browser with speed search.
>
> `Wcd` was modeled after Norton Change Directory (NCD). NCD appeared first in The Norton Utilities, Release 4, for DOS in 1987, published by Peter Norton. NCD was written by Brad Kingsbury.
>
> Examples of wcd usage:
>
> ```
> wcd Desk
> ```
>
> will change to directory `/home/waterlan/Desktop`
>
> But also
>
> ```
> wcd *top
> ```
>
> will do that.

Answer (score 0):

here another implementation, history and also locate usage: https://github.com/joknarf/cdhist (compatible ksh / bash / zsh / ash shells linux* / macos / ish / msys2 / solaris implementation...)

[cdhist in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqd5u.gif)

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score -1):

I put this tool together, which combines previous solutions for storing a comprehensive global CLI history with an interactive grepping tool called percol (mapped to C^R). I use it to retrieve commands by where they were run or to find a directory by a command. It's still slick on the first machine I started using it, now with a >2 year old CLI history.

The grep tool works on both path and command, but might still be useful to you. See also 'dirs -v' in zsh

https://github.com/gawells/ariadne

Comment: this stores a CLI history with path, command and date. It's not path-only, but still useful for reverse searching dir history (bash and zsh)

Comment: I think you forgot to link to your tool. From your description, I'd suspect it is deficient in that commands only work from where they're invoked. So `cd share/man` only works if I'm already in /usr.

Comment: oops! my bad, I thought I'd put the url in the text, didn't notice something went wrong