# What does 'd' do in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just downloaded oh-my-zsh and found out that 'd' has been taken over by some command I do not know. Does anybody know what the output from this is?

```
0   ~/Desktop/Dropbox/project_Sites/rails_app/app/views/static_pages
1   ~/Desktop/Dropbox/project_Sites/rails_app/app/views
2   ~/Desktop/Dropbox/project_Sites/rails_app
3   ~/Desktop/Dropbox/project_Sites
4   ~/Desktop/Dropbox
5   ~
6   ~/.oh-my-zsh
7   ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins
8   ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/rails
9   ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib
```

Comment: I didn't know that oh-my-zsh did any such thing. If it is reproducible then this is an interesting question.

Comment: Just for the benefit of those who don't know what oh-my-zsh is - is it [this?](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/#readme)

Comment: yes  @JourneymanGeek it is that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a history of most recent directories you've been in. `which d` identifies it as an alias to `dirs` shell builtin, which prints the contents of the directory stack. Just tried it and number keys allow to move to respective directory. Cool feature :)

Answer (score 29):

The `d` command is a function defined in [directories.zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/directories.zsh). It lists the recently visited directories, which you can navigate to directly using the number aliases defined in the same file. So for example:

```
➜  ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins (master) ✗ d
0   ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins
1   ~/.oh-my-zsh
2   ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib
3   ~
➜  ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins (master) ✗ 2
~/.oh-my-zsh/lib
➜  ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib (master) ✗
```